# How to increase variable value in rename command

Tags: rename

I want to rename files as increasing number format like this:

```
04.jpg
05.jpg
06.jpg
```

Therefore I need to file a way to increase variable value and pass it to `rename`. Somehow the internet told me to do this:

```
rename -n 'our $i; s/\d+/sprintf("new\/%03d", $i++)/e' *.*
```

The point is I don't understand how this work. So far, I can only guess that `our $i` will response to pass reference of unknown `$i` variable to rename. Then it will be add one in `sprintf("new\/%03d", $i++)` part. From that conclusion, I decided to try this:

```
i=4
rename -n 'our $i; s/\d+/sprintf("new\/%03d", $i++)/e' *.*
```

And it failed. How can I set starter value for `$i` so rename can work as I expect?

Comment: Your shell does not replace variables in single quotes (`'`)

Comment: @Panki, it's not a shell variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv
n=0; zmv -n '*.jpg(#qn[1,100])' 'new/${(l[2][0])$((++n))}.jpg'
```

Would rename up to 100 jpeg files (list numerically sorted).

(remove the `-n` for dry run if happy).

With `perl`-based `rename`s and basic shells, you could do something approaching (without the numerical sorting of the original list nor the safeguards of `zmv` though) with:

```
rename -n '
  our $i //= 1;
  exit if $i > 100;
  $_ = sprintf "new/%02d.jpg", $i++' ./*.jpg
```

`rename` runs the given `perl` code for each file in a loop with the name of the current file in `$_`. The code is meant to change `$_` to the new name for the file.

Here `our $i` defines the scope of the `$i` variable. You don't want *local* scope as in `my $i` as you want the incremented value of `$i` to be remembered from one file to the next, hence `our` (see `perldoc -f our` for details).

The `s/regexp/replacement/flags` perl construct is to do regexp substitution on the contents of `$_`. You don't need it here if you're building the replacement name from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But assuming I want to $i to start from 4 and keep increasing. How should I do? If I declare `our $i=4`, it won't be increasing in the rename loop right? Where should I declare it?

Comment: @ngdangtu, you could replace the `our $i++` with `our $i //= 3; $i++`

Answer (score 0):

The. Start index can be supplied as the first argument.

```
perl -le '
  my $i=shift;
  my $w=length(@ARGV+$i);
  -f $_ and
rename($_,sprintf("new/%0${w}d.jpg",$i++))
  or  die("moving $_:$!")
      for @ARGV;
' 4 ./*.jpg

tree -F
```

**output**

```
Before renaming step...
.
├── food1.jpg
├── food2.jpg
├── food3.jpg
├── food4.jpg
├── food5.jpg
├── food6.jpg
├── food7.jpg
├── food8.jpg
├── food9.jpg
├── infile
├── new/
└── x

After renaming step....

.
├── infile
├── new/
│   ├── 04.jpg
│   ├── 05.jpg
│   ├── 06.jpg
│   ├── 07.jpg
│   ├── 08.jpg
│   ├── 09.jpg
│   ├── 10.jpg
│   ├── 11.jpg
│   └── 12.jpg
└── x
```

Answer (score 0):

In `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `find . -type f -name "[0-9]*.jpg" -printf "%f\n" | sort -r`; do
    # Take the prefix (01.jpj --> 01)
    index="${f%.*}"

    # Remove the leading zero if have it
    index="${index#0*}"

    # add one to the index
    index=$((index+1))

    # Add again the leading zero if we are under the double
    [ "$index" -gt 10 ] || index="0$index"

    # Rename
    mv "$f" "$index.jpg"
done
```

Or the same approach, but with `python3`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import re

all_file = [ _[:_.index(".")] for _ in os.listdir() if re.match(r'^\d+(?=\.jpg$)', _)]
all_file.sort(reverse=True)

for ftr in all_file:
    ni = "0" + str(int(ftr) + 1) if int(ftr) < 9 else str(int(ftr) + 1)
    os.rename(ftr + ".jpg", ni + ".jpg")
```